# move_base crashed when call clear_costmaps service

Tags: ros, navigation, move-base, clear-costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I download the latest updated navigation package from github.And I come across a problem .move_base crashed when I call clear_costmaps service at high rate,such as 2Hz.

below is the error infomation:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
  what():  std::bad_alloc
[move_base-1] process has died [pid 16226, exit code -6, cmd /home/robocup/catkin_ws/devel/lib/move_base/move_base /move_base/clear_costmaps:=/clear_costmaps __name:=move_base __log:=/home/robocup/.ros/log/ad85e5de-ed8f-11e3-b90b-0015005e1628/move_base-1.log].
log file: /home/robocup/.ros/log/ad85e5de-ed8f-11e3-b90b-0015005e1628/move_base-1*.log
```

Has anyone met the problem before?Any advice will be appreciated!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172948/move_base-crashed-when-call-clear_costmaps-service/) by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 148 on 2014-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Calling clear costmaps at a high rate is probably not tested -- as it is not a common use case. Typically this service is called only periodically when there is too much garbage in the costmaps. If you find yourself calling this frequently, you might want to look at why, and figure out what in your use case causes you to do this.

You might also file a ticket and/or open a pull request if you find a solution to the segfault.

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on 2014-06-08**:
Thank you very much for your answer,Michael.The problem I came across is described here.
http://answers.ros.org/question/172915/why-the-costmaps-dont-clear-obstacles-in-time-when-using-move_base-package/

**Comment by [Yuichi Chu](https://answers.ros.org/users/9086/yuichi-chu/) on 2014-06-08**:
And I thought maybe calling clear costmaps periodically can solve the problem.Then  the error occured like I have   described above. Is there another way to solve the previous problem?